# Changing the value of a `*_id_seq` table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following **table** in `postgresql`: `myapp_mymodel_id_seq`

```
    Column     |  Type   |           Value            
---------------+---------+----------------------------
 sequence_name | name    | myapp_mymodel_id_seq
 last_value    | bigint  | 3
 start_value   | bigint  | 1
 increment_by  | bigint  | 1
 max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807
 min_value     | bigint  | 1
 cache_value   | bigint  | 1
 log_cnt       | bigint  | 32
 is_cycled     | boolean | f
 is_called     | boolean | t
```

**How do I change `3` under `Value` and `last_value` to `40`?**

I tried updating `last_value` but it won't recognize the column.

```
UPDATE myapp_mymodel_id_seq SET Value=40 WHERE Value=3;

ERROR:  column "value" does not exist
```

Comment: That is **not** a table, it's a sequence.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that this distinction was made. I'll leave the title like this because people who search for a similar answer probably won't know that it isn't a table either.

Comment: A sequence is something like a *special table* in Postgres.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select setval('myapp_mymodel_id_seq', 40);
```

See the manual for more details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

Comment: I'm surprised that this automatically targets `last_value` and not another 'field'/'attribute' (not sure about terminology)

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE myapp_mymodel_id_seq SET last_value = 40 WHERE last_value = 3;

Comment: myapp_mymodel_id_seq is a *sequence*, not a table. You cannot update sequences like that.